# To test a condition on all values in a list before proceeding to the next line

Tags: python

A simple attempt to create a list of prime numbers

```
l = []
r = []
q = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]
for x in range(200):
    l.append(x)
for y in l:
    for p in q:
        if y % p > 0:
            r.append(y)
print r
```

It is there for all to see that this would be a failure since the condition y %  p is not tested on all values of p in q before proceeding to the next line .

 The question - how do I test the condition y % p for all values of p in q before going to the next line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [`all` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

For instance:

```
>>> y=25
>>> all(y%p>0 for p in q)
False
>>> y=29
>>> all(y%p>0 for p in q)
True
```

In your example:

```
>>> l=range(2,200)
>>> r=[]
>>> for y in l:
...   if all(y%p for p in q):
...      r.append(y)
...
>>> r
[29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, ...]
```